# Need help setting default webpage for Google Cloud website

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a static website hosted on Google Cloud Platform.  I have set the MainPageSuffix in the website configuration to index.html.  If I go to the top-level, then that page is displayed. If I got to any subdirectory, though, I just get a page that says 'placeholder'.  How do I make the subdirectories also respect the default of 'index.html'?

Thanks!

Comment: Reading here ... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web#description

It seems like it should work.  Can you give an example of it not working?  For example, if you create a subdriectory in your bucket called photos AND create an index.html in that subdirectory ... does it display?   In your current story ... do you actually have an index.html in each subdirectory?

Comment: I used both the gsutil command and the web interface to set the main page.  I hadn't set an error page, but I don't think that should affect things.  Just to be sure, I set that right now, too.  Anyway, yes, if I go to www.<mysite>.com/photos/ I get just the text 'placeholder'.  But if I go to www.<mysite>.com/photos/index.html it works just fine. I've also tried just mysite.com/photos/ and that doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google tech support solved it.  I had an empty object in the directory. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#empty-obj